# Issue while understanding Big Oh notations?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

According to CourseEra course on Algorithms and [Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844) 
, a function G(n) where n is the input size is said to be a big oh notation of F(n) when there exists constants n0 and C such that this inequality holds true

F(n) <= C*G(N) ( For all N > N0 )

Now , 
This mathematical definition is very clear to me .

But as it was taught to me by my teacher today , I am confused!

He said that "Big - Oh Notations are upper bound on a function and it is like the LCM of two numbers i.e. Unique and greater than the function"

I don't think this statement was kind of correct, Is Big Oh notation really unique ?

Morover,
Thinking about Big Oh notations , I also confused myself why do we approximate the Big Oh notations to the highest degree term . ( We can easily prove the mathematical inequality though with nice choice of constants ) but what is the real use of it ?? 
I mean what does it signify?
We can even take F(n) as the Big Oh Notation of F(n) for the constant 1 !

I think it shows the dependence of the running time only on the highest degree term! Please Clear my doubts as I might have understood it wrongly from my book or my teacher made an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Big Oh notation really unique ?

Yes and no. By the pure formula, Big-O is of course not unique. However, to be of use for its purpose, one actually tries to find not just *some* upper bound, but the *lowest* upper bound. And this makes a meaningful "Big-O" unique.

> We can even take F(n) as the Big Oh Notation of F(n) for the constant
>   1 !

Yes we probably can do that. However, the Big-O is used to relate classes of functions/algorithms to each other. Saying that F(n) relates to X(n) like F(n) relates to X(n) is what you get by using G(n) = F(n). Not much value in that.

That's why we try to find the unique lowest G to satisfy the equation. G(n) is usually a rather trivial function, like G(n) = n, G(n) = n², or G(n) = n*log(n), and this allows us to compare algorithms more easily because we can easily see that, e.g., G(n) = n is less than G(n) = n² for all n >= something.

Interestingly, most algorithms' complexity converges to one of the simple G(n) for large n. You could also say that, by looking at large n's, we try to separate out the "important" from the not-so-important parts of F(n); then we just omit the minor terms in F(n) and get a simplified function G(n).

In practical terms, we also want to abstract away from technical details. If I have, for instance, F(n) = 4*n and E(n) = 2*n I can use twice as much CPUs for the F algorithm and be just as good as the E one independent of the size of the input. Maybe one machine has a dedicated instruction for sqare root, so that SQRT(x) is a single step, while another machine needs much more instructions to get the result. We want to abstract away from that.

This implies one more point of view too: If I have a problem to solve, e.g. "calculate x(y)", I could present the solution as "result := x(y)", O(1). But that's not considered an algorithm. The specification of the algorithm must include a relevant level of detail to be a) meaningful and b) accessible to Big-O.

Comment: Why don't we take F(n) where F(n) is the running time as the Big-O notation of F(n)? It contains constants though  and lower order terms too, but it also does satisfy the definition !
Does it get more meaningful when we say the running time is highest order term ? Just because the running time majorly depends on it ?

Comment: Yes, for comparisons of complexities this is what we want. "less is more", so to speak.

Comment: There are, however, cases where Big-O is given in more detail. Especially when it comes to optimizations of existing algorithms, we want/need to specifiy lower order terms for comparison. In these situations it may be relevant to state if we have O(2*n) or O(1.5*n).